# Converting a byte array (byte[]) to String changes one special character

Tags: java, string, encoding, byte, converters

In Java, I try to convert a byte array (`byte[]`) xml into a string using:

```
String output = new String(myXMLbyteArray, "UTF-8");
```

This is successful except for one special character, the acute apostrophe. When comparing the input and output in hex I have this:

For example:

- `40` becomes `40 00`
- `55` becomes `55 00`

But the special character `92` becomes `19 20` instead of `92 00`.

How can I fix this elegantly? I tried both the default String constructor and other encodings with no luck.

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what you are doing because `92` becoming `19 20` doesn't make sense nor does `92 00`  For example, with UTF-8 and most encodings `40` becomes `40` i.e. it is ASCII and not changed.

Comment: When I open the input text (byte[]) with a hex editor a character, for example, has the hex value 55. When I open the output text(String), that character has now value 55 00, since the char in Java is 2 bytes. That's why you would expect 92 to become 92 00, however it becomes 19 20, which is another (invalid) character.

Comment: 55 is still 55 but really it's 0055, the byte order is a hardware detail not specified by Java.  What 92 is translated to depends on your encoding. It could be 0092 if you use ISO-8859-1 but if you use UTF-8, it is the start of a multi-byte character so it needs to look at the next character to turn it into one char.

Comment: do you think it's a matter of a different encoding in the string constructor? also, could 19 20 (which can be read as 1 92 0), be a bitwise shift of 92 gone wrong? if it was a matter of the encoding, wouldn't i get entirely different numbers here?

Comment: That is what I suggested in my answer, except encoding is rarely a simple shift.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want is ISO-8859-1 which translates 0-255 to 0-255 as is.  This means (byte) 92 => (char) 92

You cannot say 55 becomes 55 00 as these are not two bytes you can access individually, it is one char which will be 0055 or just 55 if you print this as hex.

Comment: I have now tried ISO-8859-1 but I got exactly the same result. I also tried US-ASCII and got the same result. I also tried UTF-16, UTF-16LE and UTF16-BE but I was not able to get any output as this broke the server call. I am thinking that this has to do with the conversion of the byte[] to string, i.e. of each byte to a char rather than the encoding.

Comment: The encoding is the conversion from byte[] to a String.  Can you provide a real example I can run to reproduce your issue? i.e. actual Java code.